# How to fit my picture inside a div when I hover it?

Tags: javascript, html

I got some elements and when I hover them a picture should appear in the `div`. Now the problem is that, when my picture appears, it's not cut off at the end of the `div`. It just goes further below the `div`. How can I make it be cut off at the end of the `div`?

html

```
 <div class='shop-card'>
                <div class="title">
                  <?php echo "$thisComposer $thisTitle"; ?>    
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                  <div>
                    <img src="img/genre.png" alt="">
                    <?php echo "$thisGenre"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <img src="img/instrument.png" alt=""> 
                    <?php echo "$thisInstrument1"; ?>
                    <?php echo "$thisInstrument2"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <img src="img/pen.png" alt=""> 
                    <?php echo "$thisArrangement"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <?php echo "$thisDifficulty"; ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product">
                  <img src="img/<?php echo "$thisSheet"; ?>"></img>
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.shop-card {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  transition: 1s;
}
.shop-card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  scale: 1.02;
}
.shop-card:hover > .product img {
  display: block;
}
.shop-card:hover > .desc {
  display: none;
}

.product img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use object-fit:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```
object-fit: contain;
```

Comment: Oh, wow it's that easy. Thanks!